# How to have Azure Devops Pipelines triggered by Prs but not by other commits

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am using the yaml pipelines in Azure DevOps Pipelines and I see they have two specific trigger keys `trigger` and `pr`.

I want it setup so that a few pipelines I have to run tests and security checks only run when a PR on a feature branch or bugfix branch is created (or appended to) but not when they are just pushing to a feature or bugfix branch that does not have a PR yet.

Here is what I have for the `pr` key:

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - bugfix/*
      - feature/*
  paths:
    include:
      - Source/Frontend/*
```

This is for a js frontend pipeline that runs tests, linting, and coverage so I have it limited to only changes to the folder that contains the frontend code.

What do I set the `trigger` key to in order to accomplish the above stated goal?

I have tried leaving it as default by excluding a `trigger` key in my yaml file, but that just picks up every commit in any folder. I have also tried `trigger: none` but that seems to stop it from running at all. And I have also tried have the `trigger` key be the same as the `pr` key, but when I make a PR, it is not fired off.

I have ensured that the trigger overrides in Azure DevOps are turned off, so it should be going off of whatever is in the yaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my problem was two-fold.

@Hugh Lin - MSFT helped a bit, but what prevented it from working was the following:

1. I thought the branches included in the pr key were where the PR was coming from not be merged into, so I changed that from `bugfix/*` and `feature/*` to just `develop`.
2. The pipeline yaml only existed in a branch off of develop and did not exist in the develop branch.

Answer (score 3):

I tested adding `trigger: none`, which can prevent pipeline from being triggered by CI.

```
trigger: none 
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

[image]

In addition , you can also tell Azure Pipelines to skip running a pipeline that a commit would normally trigger. Just include `[skip ci]` in the commit message or description of the HEAD commit and Azure Pipelines will [skip running CI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits).

You can use any of the variations below:

- `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]`
- `skip-checks: true` or `skip-checks:true`
- `[skip azurepipelines]` or `[azurepipelines skip]`
- `[skip azpipelines]` or `[azpipelines skip]`
- `[skip azp]` or `[azp skip]`
- `***NO_CI***`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation on the `pr` block. It is only for GitHub repos. For Azure DevOps repos, use branch policies to configure PR builds.

You want `trigger: none` with an accompanying branch policy.

Comment: I am using GitHub as the repo and it is connected via the installed App. I am not using Azure DevOps repo.